# What's wrong with my javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYZLT/2/

but when I put it live online http://bellated.us.lt/supersized/index.html it doesnt work. What I am missing here?

My code:

html:

```
<div class="ball">Demo</div>
```

css:

```
.ball{
    -webkit-border-radius:250px;
    -moz-border-radius: 250px;
    border-radius: 250px;
    background: green;
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ball').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width : '250px', height : '250px', lineHeight : '250px'}, 300);
        }, 
 function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({width : '200px', height : '200px', lineHeight : '200px'}, 200)
         });
</script>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle code didn't work for me ... nothing happened when I hovered. Tested in IE 9 and FF

Comment: Please include a relevant portion of your code in your post (not just in a link) along with what you intend it to do and what it does instead...

Comment: There is no JavaScript code in that jsFiddle

Comment: @rlb.usa: That's because there's only webkit commands there, which are only for developmental testing purposes. You should not use them on a live site.

Comment: There was javascript, somebody updated

Comment: animuson>>so what I have to get rid of?

Comment: he's referring to the css3 stuff in the :hover psuedoselector of ball.. your javascript could be good -- check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your fiddle you have this:

```
.ball:hover{
 -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.5,1.5);        
}
```

but no javascript.. which is why it works in the fiddle, but only with webkit CSS3-happy browsers..

in your page where it's not working you have script

```
<script>  
$('.ball').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width : '250px', height : '250px', lineHeight : '250px'}, 300);
        },
 function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({width : '200px', height : '200px', lineHeight : '200px'}, 200)
         });
</script>
```

but you're missing document ready, try:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ball').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width : '250px', height : '250px', lineHeight : '250px'}, 300);
            },
     function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({width : '200px', height : '200px', lineHeight : '200px'}, 200)
             });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your js code in the document.ready i.e $(function(){ // your code })